# Hero image slideshow overlapping with fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website for a small company from scratch to improve my html/css/js skills, thus I'd like to avoid using any frameworks like bootstrap for this.

The site in question has a fixed navbar and a hero image slider, but I'm having an issue where the hero image temporarily overlaps the navbar each time it changes. I've tried a few things in the css but thus far I've been unable to identify the issue, which you can see here:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("headerimg");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex"; 
  setTimeout(carousel, 5000); 
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: auto 0;
 /* background-color:rgb(231,232,233); */
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size:2em;
}

nav {height:10vh;}

.mainnav {
 list-style:none;
 display:flex;
 margin: 0;
 background-color:white;
 font-size:1em;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 /* opacity:0.5; */
 }

.navitem {
 padding-top:2%;
 padding-bottom:2%;
 padding-right:6%;
 padding-left:1%;
 transition: background-color 0.3s linear; 
 }


.navitem:hover {
 background-color:red;
}

.navitem a {
 transition: color 0.3s linear; 
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-align:center;
}

.navitem a:hover {color:white;}

#tagline {
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"Lato";
 font-size:2em;
 margin-bottom:1%;
 color:black;
 background-color:#ededed;
 padding-bottom:0.5%;
 padding-top:0.2%;
 border-top:3px solid red;
}

.title {
 margin-right:auto;
 padding: 1% 6% 1% 1%;
 margin-top:auto;
 margin-bottom:auto;
 }

.title img {
 height:50px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .2} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .2} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}


.headerimg {
 max-height:400px; 
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Testing Testing</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul class="mainnav"> 
   <li class="title"><img src="logo1.png"><p style="float:right;"><strong>Testing Testing</strong></p></li>
   <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Início</a> </li>
   <li class="navitem"><a href="about.html">Sobre nós</a> </li>
   <li class="navitem"><a href="produtos.html">Produtos</a> </li>
   <li class="navitem"><a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a> </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <header style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
  <img class="headerimg fade" src="http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/central/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/header.jpg" >
  <img class="headerimg fade" src="https://www.freewebheaders.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/clouds-sky/clouds-sky-header-2063-1024x300.jpg" >
  <img class="headerimg fade" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/05/09/31/banner-1571858__340.jpg" >
 </header>
 <div id="tagline">
  <strong>LOREM IPSUM</strong>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ahotlinetogod/pen/EMOgyb)

I would appreciate any insight into this, particularly an explanation as to why it happened as like I said, this is primarily a learning exercise for me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set z-index property on .mainnav like this.
you can check this site for z-index description : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("headerimg");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex"; 
  setTimeout(carousel, 5000); 
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: auto 0;
 /* background-color:rgb(231,232,233); */
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size:2em;
}

nav {height:10vh;}

.mainnav {
 list-style:none;
 display:flex;
 margin: 0;
 background-color:white;
 font-size:1em;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 /* opacity:0.5; */
 z-index:1; /* add z-index to force always on top, as overlapped elements doesnt have this property */
 }

.navitem {
 padding-top:2%;
 padding-bottom:2%;
 padding-right:6%;
 padding-left:1%;
 transition: background-color 0.3s linear; 
 }


.navitem:hover {
 background-color:red;
}

.navitem a {
 transition: color 0.3s linear; 
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-align:center;
}

.navitem a:hover {color:white;}

#tagline {
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"Lato";
 font-size:2em;
 margin-bottom:1%;
 color:black;
 background-color:#ededed;
 padding-bottom:0.5%;
 padding-top:0.2%;
 border-top:3px solid red;
}

.title {
 margin-right:auto;
 padding: 1% 6% 1% 1%;
 margin-top:auto;
 margin-bottom:auto;
 }

.title img {
 height:50px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .2} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .2} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}


.headerimg {
 max-height:400px; 
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Testing Testing</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul class="mainnav"> 
   <li class="title"><img src="logo1.png"><p style="float:right;"><strong>Testing Testing</strong></p></li>
   <li class="navitem"><a href="#">Início</a> </li>
   <li class="navitem"><a href="about.html">Sobre nós</a> </li>
   <li class="navitem"><a href="produtos.html">Produtos</a> </li>
   <li class="navitem"><a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a> </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <header style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
  <img class="headerimg fade" src="http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/central/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/header.jpg" >
  <img class="headerimg fade" src="https://www.freewebheaders.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/clouds-sky/clouds-sky-header-2063-1024x300.jpg" >
  <img class="headerimg fade" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/05/09/31/banner-1571858__340.jpg" >
 </header>
 <div id="tagline">
  <strong>LOREM IPSUM</strong>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I'll look into the w3schools page for more info on this property. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because position fixed essentially removes the element from the document flow causing the items below it to move up.

You need to account for the space the fixed nav was previously occupying. Giving the header element padding-top: 56px; or the body element padding-top: 56px; takes care of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why it's happening (makes sense!), however adding the padding only solves the problem when the page is in its starting position - if you scroll down so that the fixed header overlaps the hero images it still 'blinks' in and out of the page when the images change, unless I'm missing something. I tried adding the padding to both the body and the .headerimg class.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Padding in combo with the z-index fix should work.